# SQLite - Remove Decimal from Column

Tags: sql-server, decimal, rounding, nvarchar

I'm trying to remove a decimal place from all the values in a nvarchar(55) column in SQLite (using Aqua Data Studio). All of the fields have a .0 at the end, which I'm trying to remove, without rounding any of the other figures.

Example: 123456.0
Desired: 123456

I've tried the below, and receive this error: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '8514838.0' to data type int.'

```
SELECT cast(column as int) from data
```

Is there any other method to remove just the trailing decimals without rounding?

Comment: Are you using SQLite? as `SELECT cast(123456.0 as int)` works fine, doing what you want.

Comment: Yes - using SQLite. I tried to run the same command on the column, but ran into the error listed above. Is there a way to convert the entire column without needing to go through each item individually?

Comment: You are NOT using SQLite; this error message can come only from MS SQL Server.

Comment: Apologies - that is correct. is there a way to fix in MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    tableName
SET
    column = SUBSTRING( column, 1, LEN( column ) - 2 )
WHERE
    column LIKE '%.0'
```

In SQL Server, strings indexes are 1-based, so `SUBSTRING( s, 1, n )` returns all of `n` characters of the string from the start.